# Calling a servlet when page initializes

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Let's say my website is http://www.xyz.com
and I want to call http://www.xyz.com?blahblah

I am using a servlet filter with

`<filter-mapping> 
 <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>`

but it is not being called on url www.xyz?blahblah

does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `url-pattern` to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

that will intercept each request.

Comment: and your title says something different. Please be clear if this doesn't answer your question

Comment: Actually that is not working, I also tried with /*. Oh and Sorry for the title.

Comment: It should be `/*` and are there any other filter that by passes the request or something ?

Comment: nope I only have one filter. My hipothesis is that filters only work when a servlet is called, and the request is first redirected to the filter. However, There is no servlet mapped to the root url, so how could that work?

Comment: `/*` means every request, `*.html` means every request with url ending `.html`